# Cursor is not updating my column

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

am using cursor to update my null column but it is not updating

```
Declare @Itemcode as varchar(30)
Declare @SLV as varchar(20)
declare cursor1 cursor for 
Select Itemcode ,U_SLV from  oitm_Clone where sapitem is null and u_slv is null
open cursor1 
  fetch next FROM cursor1 INTO @Itemcode ,@SLV
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   begin
   if @SLV is null
   begin
   declare @sql1 as varchar(max)        
          set @sql1 = 'Update [dbo].oitm_Clone set sapitem ='''+ @Itemcode +''' where ItemCode='''+ @Itemcode +''' and U_SLV ='''+ @SLV +''''
          print @sql1
          execute (@sql1)
   end
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @Itemcode ,@SLV
   end
    CLOSE cursor1
DEALLOCATE cursor1
```

Comment: Are this correct? `sapitem ='''+ @Itemcode +'''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need a cursor to do this update. Try this simple update which has the same logic of your cursor with much improved performance.

```
Update [dbo].oitm_Clone 
Set sapitem = itemcode
Where sapitem is null and u_slv is null
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
```

instead of

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
```

hope it will help you

regards